# In ASP.NET remove session variables older than fifteen minutes

Tags: asp.net, session, pageload

I have ASP.NET default page which clears all of the session variables in page_load method like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
}
```

but I want to remove session variables only older than fifteen minutes  in page_load method.

how can I remove only old session variables?

Comment: IMHO session is reset after 15 min by default.

Comment: @RoyiNamir in ASP.NET the default is [20 mins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: these are idle timeout values; i think the OP wants to remove unused variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave session expiration to the framework unless you have good reason to do it manually (which you don't appear to have). You can adjust the [SessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property accordingly so that your sessions expire after 15 minutes (the default is 20 minutes) e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="15" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: at the end of timeout,will all of the session variables be cleared up or just older than fifteen minutes?

Comment: @James , I believe he wants to clear only "some" session vars after 15 minutes.

Comment: @verdery this expires the entire session, so all the variables. Are you looking for *specific* variables to be cleared after X amount of time but keep the session alive? `RemoveAll` is the equivalent of calling `Clear` which does effectively the same as the session expiring...

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is to create custom objects, storing my actual data that I want to keep, as well as a timestamp. This way, you don;t alter the default session behaviour, and cann have different objects expire at different time intervals.

I then, when I perform certain actions, look at this object, measure its timestamp to the current time, and clear that object if it meets my time difference.

```
Class mycustomobject
Property thisObject as object '<- store your object you want to keep here, 
                              'even define as type of your specific object...

Property timestamp as datetime
End class

Dim MySessionSaveObject as new mycustomobject

with MySessionSaveObject
.object = 'Whatever you want to save...
.timestamp = now
end with


session(mySessionVar) = MySessionSaveObject
```

I think you can determine the rest?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to have individual items expire automatically is (mis)use the built-in timeout of **Cache**. Use a cachekey of your fixed "session" key plus the current SessionId. Then you can also specify a sliding timeout of 20 minutes.

So instead of

```
Session["MyKey"] = value;
```

you use

```
Cache.Insert("MyKey" + Session.SessionID, value, null, 
   TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20), Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
```